# Pass HTML element to a class function

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, class

I want to declare a function in a class that gets an HTML tag as a parameter.
Something like this:

`public void className(div myDiv) { myDiv.innertext = "Hello"; }`

and then call it like this:

`className(myDiv);`

Code does not detect my HTML element.

Comment: So? What's preventing you from doing what you want to accomplish?

Comment: What version of asp.net? and where are you calling this from? a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking but this may get you closer to what you need.

```
public void className(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl myDiv)
{
    // do stuff with the div object
    myDiv.InnerText = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The only thing that I needed is: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl